# Continuous data stream using DataFlow and RX stops processing

Tags: .net, async-await, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

I have setup a system to read messages from a queue indefinitely, then farm them off using Rx and `TPL DataFlow`.

For some reason, after a few hundred messages the ActionBlock stops running hangs and I cannot figure out why. `this.GetMessages()` continues to fire but `this.ProcessMessages` no longer does.

```
var source = Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
    .SelectMany(x => this.GetMessages());

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<List<QueueStream>>(
    this.ProcessMessages,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2,
    });

using (source.Subscribe(actionBlock.AsObserver()))
{
    while (this.Run)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}

actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
```

**The reader - Note that this actually continues to run**

```
private async Task<List<QueueStream>> GetMessages()
{
    var messageList = new List<QueueStream>();
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    // Add up to N items in our queue
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        var task = this
            .ReadAndParseQueue()
            .ContinueWith(async queueStreamTask =>
                {
                    var queueStream = await queueStreamTask;
                    if (queueStream != null)
                    {
                        messageList.Add(queueStream);
                    }
                });

        taskList.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    return messageList;
}
```

**The writer - after a few hundred messages this stops getting hit**

```
private async Task ProcessMessages(List<QueueStream> streams)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var queueStream in streams)
    {
        tasks.Add(this.ProcessMessage(queueStream));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. Something that we can copy-paste-and-run code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @Chris what is the state of the `ActionBlock` once it _hangs_, it is likely that it is faulted. Any exception thrown from within `ProcessMessages` will not be observed until you `await` completion which in your case would never happen if `this.run` is always set.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your `source` keeps running in this case? There is an infinite loop in your code, but, if error occurs or `this.Run` is unset, it will stop, and after that you have these lines:

```
actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
```

which actually prevents the `actionBlock` to accept new mesasges, so `ProcessMessages` will never being called, as messages are simply being ignored.